# JScrollpane crashes in IE when content is created using JavaScript

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I'm using JScrollpane on a number of portlets, each pulling content from different sources.

One of the sources contains a JavaScript file, this then builds the html using a series of document.write() calls.  There is nothing too difficult in the html that is created, just a few list objects, hyperlinks, and a couple of images, and there are no Flash elements.

When I try to put a JSCrollpane on this content, I get "*Internet Explorer has encountered a problem and needs to close.*"  This only happens in IE 8, in Chrome and Firefox there are no issues.

I have no control over the content and cannot change it.

I am using JQuery v1.6.1 and jScrollpane v2.0beta10.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  A page created through document.write() calls hanging when jquery's $(document).ready() fires.  Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

is your code within a $(document).ready() block?

Another common cause of that error is having a background image on the body tag while using jquery 1.6.2, however you are using 1.6.1 so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: The call to .jScrollPan() is done from a  $(document).ready() block yes.  However i have tried putting it in a seperate function and caling it manually from the console when the rest of the page is loaded and stable, the problem still occurs.

The document.write() calls which are being used to generate the html is not within a  $(document).ready() block. 

There is no image on body.